# Displaying timestamps which occurred in another timezone

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

I would like to be able to display the time of an event which occurred in another timezone as follows

> 7:01am, 22 November (NZDT)

However DateTimeOffset only stores the numeric offset for the point in time not the timezone which produced that offset.

Is there a more appropriate SQL/.Net type which allows storing the actual originating timezone information or do I need store it as 2 seperate columns/a custom .net type?

Answer (score 1):

You do need to store the zone or something else that can help you reconstruct what you need. The .NET class that helps is [the TimeZoneInfo class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If you look it up, you will see that it has built-in serialization. It has some dependency on the time zones available on the system, but has a way around by allowing custom time zones. I think it'll help you.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @g-stoynev it will be necessary to store the time zone - as for any given timezone offset there may be multiple timezones.

An alternate solution to the TimeZoneInfo class is the Nodatime library (http://nodatime.org/) - which has classes that store both the actual time and associated timezone information together - and draws timezone information from a comprehensive list of timezones sourced from the IANA timezone database (http://www.iana.org/time-zones).

Irrespective of whether you use the library there is a lot of useful information on representation of dates available within the documentation (http://nodatime.org/1.2.x/userguide/concepts.html)